# lombok @Builder on method

Tags: java, lombok

I want to use fluent Api to reduce the parameter list of a method. I dont want to create a constructor for this, so I annote the method with Lombok-@Builder:

```
@Builder
public static void test(User user, Item item, int age, Map<String, Test> tests, LocalDateTime time, String desc){
        ..method related things..
}
```

Now, I expect to call that method with the Fluent-Api of @Builder:

```
test.withUser(u).withItem(i)...build();
```

However, as I do not have any getters and setters around the method, no fluent Api exists for that method. Is this the right use of @Builder on a method?

Comment: To be honest, I had only ever used Builder on classes. I didn't even know you could put it on a method. I would totally refactor a bunch of parameters like this into a single class with a Builder. Nothing is less readable in Java than a method with a bunch of parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you use the default Builder syntax.

```
@Builder
public static void test(User user, Item item){
    // ...
}

public void buildTestExample(){
    builder()
            .user(new User())
            .item(new Item())
            .build();
}
```

However, you can specify the method name like so:

```
@Builder(builderMethodName = "buildTest")
public static void test(User bar, Item item){
    // ...
}

public void buildTestExample(){
    buildTest()
            .user(new User())
            .item(new Item())
            .build();
}
```

See https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder

> A method annotated with @Builder (from now on called the target)
>   causes the following 7 things to be generated:
>
> - An inner static class named FooBuilder, with the same type arguments
>     as the static method (called the builder).
> - In the builder: One private non-static non-final field for each parameter of the target.
> - In the builder: A package private no-args empty constructor.
> - In the builder: A 'setter'-like method for each parameter of the target: It has the same type as that parameter and the **same name**. It returns the builder
>     itself, so that the setter calls can be chained, as in the above
>     example.
> - In the builder: A build() method which calls the method,
>     passing in each field. It returns the same type that the target
>     returns.
> - In the builder: A sensible toString() implementation.
> - In the class containing the target: A builder() method, which creates a new
>     instance of the builder.

Here is an arbitrary example showing that you can have 2 Builders for 2 methods and it works fine.

```
@Builder(builderMethodName = "buildFoo")
public static String foo(String param1, String param2){
    return "foo" + param1 + param2;
}

@Builder(builderMethodName = "buildBar")
public static String bar(String param1, String param2){
    return "bar" + param1 + param2;
}

@Test
public void test(){

   assertThat(buildFoo().param1("h").param2("w").build()).isEqualTo("foohw");

   assertThat(buildBar().param1("h").param2("w").build()).isEqualTo("foohw");
}
```

Comment: Using no void return type such as @Builder(builderMethodName = "buildTest")
public static Output test(User bar, Item item){
    // ...
} does not work. Debugger says: "Return type for the method is missing"

Comment: having two methods annotated with "@Builder", then only the first method annotated with "@Builder" overwrites toString. But why I am forced to overwrite toString only to use fluent-Api for  a method?

Comment: Maybe the better way would be to have a new annotation in lombok, such as "@Fluent" which can be annotated only on a method and makes the method-call with all its properties fluently. Such as "method().addPropX().addPropY().invoke();"

Comment: @nimo23 This was the answer to your question, you are moving the goalpost, but I'll try to solve your problem. The syntax is `builder().paramName("foo).build()` You can change the `builder()` and the `build()`, but I don't think you can change `.paramName("foo")` to `.addParamName("foo")` or whatever you want.

Comment: I can't debug the rest of your code without you providing it, but this should answer your question fully.

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess I will use a object and pass the object instead of the long parameter list. By the way, I created an issue https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1464. Maybe, lombok can better the fluent-Api escpecially for method-calls

Comment: @nimo23 I don't understand, this does exactly what you said you wanted to do.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This solved the problem but there are limitations with the @Builder-Annotation such as "required parameters". And the method-calls..when String is returned for two methods then lombok creates a StringBuilder which has all the parameters of the two methods..so this is not separated.

Comment: I'm just not seeing the behavior where the parameters are combined for 2 methods as long as the builderMethodName is different.

Comment: You can use `builderClassName = "Builder1"` to change the name of the builder class from StringBuilder or whatever